# How do I override a sequelize defaultValue function for testing purposes?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm trying to add unit/integration testing to my sequelize project, and I'm running into a problem when moving from postgres dialect to sqlite. I am attempting to override the 'defaultValue' function on 'id'. This results in the syntax for CREATE TABLE being correct, but the original defaultValue is used in the INSERT statement generated by `.create()`.

I have created a [minimal sample project](https://github.com/pcsanwald/tmp/tree/master/sequelize-toy) that illustrates the problem I'm describing with a failing test.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
    User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      field: 'id',
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal("uuid_generate_v1mc()"),
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      field: "first_name"
    },
});

// why doesn't setting these attributes override the default value
// provided by User.create?
User.attributes.id.defaultValue='b9c96442-2c0d-11e6-b67b-9e71128cae77';
User.tableAttributes.id.defaultValue='b9c96442-2c0d-11e6-b67b-9e71128cae77';
```

What's the best way to inject or mock the defaultValue function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would miss the "why" part, but here is how I made it work:

```
before(function() {
    // Define a table that uses a custom default value
    User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
          type: Sequelize.UUID,
          field: 'id',
          defaultValue: sequelize.literal("uuid_generate_v1mc()"),
          primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          field: "first_name"
        },
    });

    User.attributes.id.defaultValue.val = '"b9c96442-2c0d-11e6-b67b-9e71128cae77"';

    return sequelize.sync();
});
```

Though, I suspect there should be an easier way to achieve the same result.

---

What is interesting is that if the `defaultValue` would not be `literal` or `fn` and be, say, a string value instead, things would be much easier - we could've just added a hook:

```
User.beforeCreate(function (user) {
  user.dataValues.id = 'b9c96442-2c0d-11e6-b67b-9e71128cae77';
});
```

I suggest you to seek the answers for the "why" question at the [`sequelize` issue tracker](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues).